# TypeError Obj.root is undefined ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am getting a console log output saying `TypeError: treeObj.root is undefined` on this line: `var count = treeObj.root.length;` not sure why or how to solve it?

```
   $.ajax({
        url: 'Content/data.txt',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (treeObj) {

            var count = treeObj.root.length; //here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `dataType: 'text'` you tell the ajax-call to treat the answer from the server as a plain string. Try changing that to `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: if i set it to json it still doesn't work but after I refresh like 5 times it then works? what the hell is going on?

Answer (score 1):

treeObj is most likely getting passed in as a string, not an object so you need to parse the string into an object using something along:

```
try{
   treeObj = jQuery.parseJSON(treeObj);
}catch(e){}
```